# How to check if all characters in a string are capitalized using a loop

Tags: python, string, loops

I am trying to check if each character in my string is capitalized. I have to use a loop, and cannot use regex. My idea is that the loop checks each character whether or not it is both capitalized and a known character. If it gets to a character that is not both capitalized and known, it exits the loop and returns false, otherwise it returns true.

```
        for i in range(len(s)):
            char = s[i]
            if is_capitalized(char):
                return True
            else:
                return False
                break
    else: 
        return False
```

Here is the docstring of how the function is supposed to behave.
For some reason, is_all_caps('CHATte') returns True.

```
    >>> is_all_caps('HA')
    True
    >>> is_all_caps('CHAT')
    True
    >>> is_all_caps('CHATte')
    False
```

Comment: The following is not needed for python `for i in range(len(s)): char = s[i]` the characters can be iterated through directly with `for x in s: if is_capitalized(x)`

Comment: " I have to use a loop, and cannot use regex" - why? Also, *neither* of those is the appropriate way to solve the problem. The string provides its own built-in method for this: e.g. `'CHAT'.isupper()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because as soon as a function returns a value, it ends and does not continue. Thus, as soon as it reaches a capitalised character (`if is_capitalized(char)`), it will return `True` and not check the rest of the characters.

You can take advantage of this and immediately return False once you see an invalid character, and if the for-loop reaches the end, then you know that all your characters must be valid (capitalised):

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    char = s[i]
    if not is_capitalized(char):
        return False

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need regex for this. You can use [`isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#str.isupper) like this:

```py
def is_all_caps(s):
    return all(char.isupper() for char in s)
```

```sh
>>> is_all_caps('HA')
True
>>> is_all_caps('CHAT')
True
>>> is_all_caps('CHATte')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not simply comparing the string to its fully capitalized version?

```
s == s.upper()  # returns True if all characters in the string are capitalized (or False if any of them is not)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31750329)